# Is there any VBA function to copy only the changed values from a column to another column?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, auto-update

I have a table in excel which is linked with other data source and it automatically gets updated. I am looking for a code to capture old values (only from changed cells) from column C and  placed them in column D.

I have tried this code but obviously it only captures one value at a time and it does not capture auto updated values.

```
Dim oval
```

Worksheet_SelectionChange

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
oval = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Worksheet_Change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo SkipError
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Not Intersect(Target, Me.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then

 If Target.Value <> oval Then

    Cells(Target.Row, "D").Value = oval
    End If
End If
SkipError:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I expect column D to have old values of Column C when ever it gets updated.

[image: ScreenShot-Table]

Comment: hi. if u want to run macro everytime worksheet is update u have the use the event worksheet change. Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range). it runs everytime worksheet is updated.

Comment: exactly what I am using up in my code but oval=Target.value is something probably needs to be fixed.

Comment: not the same. im sugesting you to use Worksheet_CHANGE, not Worksheet_SELECTIONCHANGE

Comment: underneath it right after 2 lines, I have `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` but you are right may be I should change `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` to something else. Problem is i need to capture multiple values not just one where as `target.value` just capture one value.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. in that case u could encapsulate  the  "If Target.Value <> oval Then " block inside a "For Each cell In rng / Next cell"

Comment: testing a litle bit, i believe this code is not working like u want. in my case the  Worksheet_Change event is always first than Worksheet_SelectionChange. so what happends is that the variable oval is getting the value of the last chage, not the current change. in the first change, oval is getting the value empty

Comment: Thank you for your help Luis.